# Foreign key or string for created/updated by auditing columns

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, database-schema, audit

In previous DB schema designs I have used free-text strings in `created_by` and `updated_by` columns.

In this application all users will automatically have a record created in the `USERS` table when they first log in. Should I use a foreign key to `USERS` as the `created_by` and `updated_by` value?

It is likely that a `USER` record would never actually be deleted, merely marked as such.

Comment: "It is likely that a USER record would never actually be deleted, merely marked as such." Then it's just as likely your relationship would work fine.  There is a small amount of additional overhead.  One thing to think about though, if you have any automated jobs that parse data in... what "created/updated" by will those be set to in the users table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest here to use foreign key here because these columns would be used in future to track the users activity in the system